# CS50 'Recover' Problem - Incomplete Images - Two Incorrect Bytes

Tags: c, cs50

First post here, hoping you can help! Apologies for the length - just trying to be thorough.

I'm working on CS50 Problem Set 4, and I've stumbled across an interesting issue that I haven't been able to resolve yet. I'm successfully recovering 49 images, and approximately half of the images appear to be correctly recovered. However, the remaining images have varying extents of "corrupt" data at the end of the files, as per the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86QCT.jpg) from Windows Explorer.

Given that this occurs in the middle of a file, and I appear to be finding the start of each file correctly, I believe this occurs in the second half of my while loop - i.e. "not a jpg header". We're told that the jpg files are stored back to back on the raw data, so I don't think I need to be accounting for anything unusual at the end of the jpg files.

I've carried out a number of tests in an attempt to resolve the issue, with no success so far:

1. Verified that total output file size is correct by comparing to card.raw.
2. Verified that the second half of my while loop runs the expected number of times for image 001.jpg - the first with an issue.
3. Running on another IDE
4. Checked if file size appears to be related to the "corrupt" files, as there's no obvious pattern to the successful/unsuccessful outputs.
5. Various syntax changes in the areas I think may be the root cause (definition of buffer variable,
   fread/fwrite statement modes.)

My final debugging endeavour was a comparison of my version of 001.jpg, with a known correct version of 001.jpg from a friend that has completed this problem set. I compared these in a hex editor, and found that two bytes (of 105984 in total) were incorrect. At line 00002400 and line 00012400, I have "d8" in place of "00" in the hex view of the jpg file. There are no further differences.

I've included the areas of code which I believe to be relevant below, along with check50 results. I'm happy to provide further code if required. I feel like I've reached the limits of my understanding at the moment, and I'm unsure on how to proceed with resolving this issue. **Can anyone give me some advice on what the issue may be here?**

**Code sample:**

```
#include <stdint.h> //required for uint8_t
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int SEG_SIZE = 512;
typedef uint8_t BYTE; //declaring byte to simplify code below

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //check if single argument has been applied, give usage instructions if not.
        //retracted
    
    //open memory card file
        // retracted code
    
    //error handle
        // retracted code
    
    //define variables
    BYTE buffer[SEG_SIZE]; //char=1 byte. 512 byte buffer for reading file.
    char img_filename[8]; 
    int count = -1; //declaring counter for number of files found. Starting at -1, allowing first found file to be number 0.
    
    //declare jpg file. Declaring in loop produces errors, local variable is 'block scoped'.
    FILE *img = NULL;

    //repeat until end of card
    while (fread(buffer, SEG_SIZE, 1, input)) //read 512 byte samples into buffer until end of file. returns number of items successfully read from file (i.e. 1)
    {
        //if start of new jpg
        if ((buffer[0]==0xff) && (buffer[1]=0xd8) && (buffer[2] == 0xff) && ((buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)) // retracted code //checking if first four bytes match the beginning of a new jpg.
        {
            count++;
            if (count == 0) //found first image in raw data.
            {
                //retracted code - creates filename and opens file.
            }
            else
            {
                //closing previous file
                // retracted code
                img = fopen(img_filename, "w"); //opening next image file.
                fwrite(buffer, SEG_SIZE, 1, img);
            }
        }
        else if (count >= 0) //required to prevent running this code before declaring a file.
        {
            fwrite(buffer, SEG_SIZE, 1, img); //continue writing to current file, if present
        }
    }
    // retracted code
}
```

**check50 results:**

```
Results for cs50/problems/2021/x/recover generated by check50 v3.2.2
:) recover.c exists.
:) recover.c compiles.
:) handles lack of forensic image
:) recovers 000.jpg correctly
:( recovers middle images correctly
    recovered image does not match
:) recovers 049.jpg correctly
```

Thanks in advance,

Andy.

Comment: I think the problem is in the "retracted" bits. I started with this program as a shell, filled in the missing bits and it passes check50.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus, can I send you a copy of my code to try to understand where the issue is?

Comment: Sure. Create a gist or a pastebin and leave the link in a comment, or edit the full code into the question, and I'll gladly have a look.

Comment: Hi @DinoCoderSaurus. I've added the full code into the question - can you have a look please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing `=` in this line:

```
if ((buffer[0]==0xff) && (buffer[1]=0xd8) && (buffer[2] == 0xff) && ((buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)) //checking if first four bytes match the beginning of a new jpg.
```

The compiler does not give  a "expression not assignable" error because parentheses change what the expression "is". `buffer[1] = 0xd8` (without parens) would give the error. With the exception of `(buffer[3] & 0xf0)`, the internal parentheses are extraneous.

Comment: Thanks @Dino. I missed this one, it doesn't seem to give an error using the "make" function on the CS50 IDE. That has resolved my issue, thanks!

Comment: the wording was rather clumsy, hopefully it is clarified now and for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE *img = NULL;

int counter = 0;
char image[8]; 

BYTE data[BLOCK];
//checking if the end of the card is reached
while (fread(&data, sizeof(BLOCK), 1, card) != 0)
{
    //checking if it's a new jpeg
    if (data[0] == 0xff && data[1] == 0xd8 && data[2] == 0xff && (data[3] & 0xf0)==0xe0)
    {
        //if it's not the first new jpeg, close the previous 
        if (img != NULL)
        {
            fclose(img);
        }

        sprintf(image, "%03i.jpg", counter);
        img = fopen(image, "w");
        if (img == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open %s!\n", image);
            fclose(card);
            return 3;
        }
        counter++;

    }
    if (img != NULL)
    {
        fwrite(&data, sizeof(BLOCK), 1, img);
    }
} 

fclose(img);
fclose(card);

return 0;
```

}